# libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 package

Tags: package-management, gtk, software-installation

In my software I am using libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 package, which is necessary for proper running of my Software. I had this package installed on all my Laptops. But when I tried to install the Software on another laptop where this package was NOT present, my software was not running properly. Then I installed the package.

I am giving this software to some of my friends who will use it daily. 1-2 of them are from remote areas where they hardly get internet. So I thought that I will provide this package separately. But I could not get it. Can anybody tell me how to resolve this issue ?
Where can I get the libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 so that I can provide it within the CD ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package is in the Ubuntu main archive. You can download it with `apt-get download libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` or by going to the [source package's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkitgtk), and downloading from there, for the appropriate architecture.

However, it would probably be better to update your program to use GTK+ 3.x and `libwebkitgtk-3.0-0` instead, which is included by default on the Ubuntu install. GTK+ 2.x is deprecated and it is not recommended to write new software with it at this time, and is recommended to port applications to GTK+ 3.x if possible.

Comment: @dobey- thanks for your very useful and informative stuff. As you have suggested to move on to GTK+3.x, I will definitely update my software. BTW I tried to download the same using the previous command, but wasn't successful... got "findIndex failed" !! I tried - apt-get download libwebkitgtk-3.0-0